# Unable to connect to Apple App Store API with JWT token

Tags: javascript, jwt

I need to generate JWT token for Store Connect API. This is my token generating code:

```
console.log(" appStoreConnectAPIFromNode.js running ‍")

const fs   = require('fs');
const jwt  = require('jsonwebtoken'); // npm i jsonwebtoken
// You get privateKey, apiKeyId and issuerId from your Apple App Store Connect account
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync("./AuthKey-XXXXXXXX.p8") // this is the file you can only download once and should treat like a real, very precious key.
const apiKeyId = "XXXXXXXX"
const issuerId = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXXXXXXXXX"
let now = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000); // Notice the /1000 
let nowPlus20 = now + 1199 // 1200 === 20 minutes

let payload = {
    "iss": issuerId,
    "exp": nowPlus20,
    "aud": "appstoreconnect-v1",
    "iat": now
}

let signOptions = {
    "algorithm": "ES256", // you must use this algorythm, not jsonwebtoken's default
    header : {
        "alg": "ES256",
        "kid": apiKeyId,
        "typ": "JWT"
    }
};

let token = jwt.sign(payload, privateKey, signOptions);
console.log('@token: ', token);

fs.writeFile('Output.txt', token, (err) => { 
      
    // In case of a error throw err. 
    if (err) throw err; 
})
```

I'm getting this response though

```
 "errors": [{
                "status": "401",
                "code": "NOT_AUTHORIZED",
                "title": "Authentication credentials are missing or invalid.",
                "detail": "Provide a properly configured and signed bearer token, and make sure that it has not expired. Learn more about Generating Tokens for API Requests https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=api-generating-tokens"
        }]
```

I thing the problem is with token(directly with signature). When I try decode token on https://jwt.io/#debugger-io, my payload and header is decoded properly. Status: Invalid Signature

What I do wrong? Any ideas how do it properly?

Comment: did you paste the public key to jwt.io? Without the public key it can't verify the signature. But the error message is "Authentication credentials are missing or invalid". Did you send the token in the header?

Comment: Yes, after the token is generated I run this command::  curl  https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps --Header "Authorization: Bearer lOOOOOOOOOOOONG_GENERATED_TOKEN"

Comment: @jps from where to get public key ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm also facing this and me and teammate solved it.....

solution:

1. remove "iat" in payload(this is important):
   like this,

```
let payload = {
     iss: *******,
     exp: *******,
     aud: "appstoreconnect-v1",
     bid: "your_bundle_id",
   };
```

2. url :
   i used axios :

```
const { data } = await axios({
     method: "GET",
     url: "https://api.storekit.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/history/",
     headers: {
       "Content-type": "application/json",
       Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
     },
   });
res.json(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently needed to solve this problem too and after following a lot of tutorials which often gave the wrong answer for the app store connect api. I found a way to make it work. This is how I did it in Java.

```
import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.interfaces.ECPrivateKey;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

// The code is like this so try it in whatever method you want, 
// break it up into pieces so it's a bit more readable

// These variables are the minimum you should need
String keyFile = "/path/to/app_store_AuthKey_XXXX.p8";
// The XXXX is the same XXXX from the keyFile filename itself
String keyId = "XXXX";
String issuerId = "1234-1234-1234-1234-1234";

FileReader kfReader = new FileReader(keyFile);
PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(kfReader);
PrivateKeyInfo info = (PrivateKeyInfo) pemParser.readObject();
byte[] pkData = info.getEncoded();

// Convert the PrivateKeyInfo object to a PKCS8EncodedKeySpec object
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pkData);

KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
ECPrivateKey privateKey = (ECPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);

Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.ECDSA256(null, privateKey);

Instant expiration = Instant.now().plus(TIMEOUT_MINUTES, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);

return JWT.create()
          .withKeyId(keyId)
          .withIssuer(issuerId)
          .withExpiresAt(expiration)
          .withAudience("appstoreconnect-v1")
          .sign(algorithm);
```

Comment: I just tested, it worked for me. You need to add bid(app bundle id ) in JWT.create(). .withClaim("bid","app bundle id").

Comment: In my case, I don't actually need that. Not sure why. But useful for others maybe need to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple sign option for this.

```js
const PRIVATE_KEY = fs.readFileSync(p8FilePath, "utf8");
const ISSUER_ID = "ID";
const KEY_ID = "Key_ID";

 let payload = {
      iss: ISSUER_ID,
      exp: NOW_PLUS_20,
      aud: "appstoreconnect-v1",
    };

    let signOptions = {
      algorithm: "ES256",
      header: {
        alg: "ES256",
        kid: KEY_ID,
        typ: "JWT",
      },
    };

    let token = jwt.sign(payload, PRIVATE_KEY, signOptions);
```

You can use this token in your API call

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to resolve my own issues dealing with making a JWT to connect to the Apple Music API and there were two things I noticed in your payload. The first, that you are adding the 1200 to the iat, fixed my issued, so thank you. The second is the function for now is returning a float. I think the API would like an int. I would try `"iat": parseInt(now)` or `now = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000)`

Answer (score -2):

According to jsonwebtoken [usage](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#jwtsignpayload-secretorprivatekey-options-callback) instructions. You can use the `options` directly on an empty payload as follows:

```js
let signOptions = {
    issuer: issuerId,
    keyid: apiKeyId,
    expiresIn: '20m',
    audience: 'appstoreconnect-v1',
    algorithm: 'ES256'
};

let token = jwt.sign({}, privateKey, signOptions);
```

Comment: Still getting the same error message after trying the above example

Comment: Strange. I'm assuming that you are positive that both "issuerId" and "apiKeyId" are correct. That leaves only 2 checks:
1. Your env date/time is actually correct. Such a simple thing might be the reason, since the signed token has a calculated expiration time.
2. You have Apple "Paid Agreements" signed and approved in your Developer Account. Even during testing, these are required by Apple.

Comment: If as of end of 2023 you are still stuck with this, this is actually the right answer for how to do this in Node, just add the bundleId in the payload object (field bid)

Comment: This will not work in the new versions. This is bit older approach for the issue in hand